# I cant use .populate properly,may be i am making some mistake

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have two collections,first one is posts and second one is users. When user is logged in and post some story it goes to collection named posts 
Post DB is like this.

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5dac6e8f6c56a17a0b15a48b"},"user":{"$oid":"5dab52a4fdcf354ee1a6c58a"},"title":"test","category":"Entertainment","description":"sss","link":"","date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1571581583510"}},"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}
```

that user contains object id of the user who posted the story
User DB is like this

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5dab52a4fdcf354ee1a6c58a"},"name":"kush","email":"keshav@gmail.com","img":"https://res.cloudinary.com/kushagent47/image/upload/v1571483341/default-profile-picture-gmail-2_zf1b6h.png","password":"$2a$10$L6L5q4imtqGTR9LoBBgOseKzFVdeU55eugHuQxhWHixnPSaiMdq4q","date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1571508900973"}},"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}
```

Post.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    tag: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    link: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    user:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'users'
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);

module.exports = Post;
```

index.js

```
   const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    const { ensureAuthenticated, forwardAuthenticated } = require('../config/auth');
    const passport = require('passport');

    const Post = require('../models/Post');
    const User = require('../models/User');




    //WELCOME
    router.get('/', (req,res) => {
      Post.find({})
      .populate('User')
      .then(docs => {
        res.render('welcome', {
          users: docs
        });
        console.log(docs.user.name);
      });
    });
    //Post Handler
    router.post('/', (req, res) => {
      const { user, title, description, category, tag, link } = req.body;
      const newPost = new Post({
        user: req.user.id,
        title: title,
        category: category,
        description: description,
        tag: tag,
        link: link
      });
      newPost.save()
      .then(
        post => {
          res.redirect('/dashboard/');
        })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
    });
    // Dashboard
    router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
      Post.find(function(err, docs){
      res.render("dashboard", {
        name: req.user.name,
        email: req.user.email,
        img: req.user.img,
        users: docs
      });
    });
    });


    module.exports = router;
```

User.ejs

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    img: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

welcome.ejs

```
<% users.forEach(function(results){ %>
    <%= results.category %>
    <%= results.user.name %>
<% }) %>
```

I am getting results.category,but i am not getting results.user.name, i have tried everything but still its not working.

When i console.log(docs) it shows me

```
[ { _id: 5dacb9028a808c1d733d8b9e,
    user: 5dab52a4fdcf354ee1a6c58a,
    title: 'IE-Caligo',
    category: 'Tech',
    description: 'eaffff',
    link: '',
    date: 2019-10-20T19:44:02.846Z,
    __v: 0 } ]
```

Comment: In `populate` it is about the actual field ..might be a typo here. Check: `Post.find({}).populate("user").exec().then(docs => {...});`

Comment: Yes, looks like you just need to use a lowercase 'u' in user

Comment: Hey @ambianBeing i tried but its not working,actually i tried everything and still its not working :-(